# How to edit and theme Comments & Comments form?

Tags: views, panels, theming, comments

I am building a drupal site using drupal 7 and the adaptivetheme.

I created some a content type called recipes. Than I created a content pane in views to present recipes in panels. I add the comments and comments form to the same panel.

Now I want to present beneath any recipe a comment form and all other comments.
My problem is that I  don't know how to edit the presentation of the comment form. When I checked the comment fields on my content type, I saw only the field "comment_body".

How can I edit the fields and the way they will show on Comments & Comments form?

Below is a screenshot. 
I want to remove the field "your name", and change the button "save" to "post comment". How can I do that?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the file called **comment.tpl.php** from the folder where base AT theme is located (something like adaptivetheme\at_core\templates) and paste it into sites\all\themes\YOUR_AT_SUBTHEME\templates.

Assuming recipes is the machine name of your content type, you can also name it **comment--recipes.tpl.php** if you want to theme specifically comments for recipes.

Then with the help of [comment.tpl.php API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.tpl.php/7) (you can also find a lot of information in the php file itself), you can edit the way your comments will be displayed.

I.e instead of

```
print render($content);
```

You can display specific fields :

```
print render($content['comment_body']);
```

or hide specific fields

```
hide($content['author']);
print render($content);
```

To alter the form itself, you need to use `hook_form_alter()` in a custom module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function YOUR_CUSTOM_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  //get the form id
  drupal_set_message("Form ID is : " . $form_id);
  $print = '<pre>' . print_r($form, TRUE) . '</pre>';
  drupal_set_message($print);

  switch($form_id){
    case 'YOUR_COMMENT_FORM_ID':
      //alter your form (with the complete correct fields names)
      $form['YOUR_FIELD_YOUR_NAME']['#type'] = 'hidden';
      $form['YOUR_FIELD_SUBMIT']['#value'] = t('Post comment');
    break;
  }
}
```

You can also use `dpm($form)` if you have Devel installed, or make a

```
$print = '<pre>' . print_r($form, TRUE) . '</pre>';
drupal_set_message($print);
```

in order to retrieve the exact form fields

Comment: Thanks! How can I access the comment form and edit the way the form appear (I want to remove the "your name" field)?

Comment: I managed to do it! Thank you!
I have one questions regarding this process - is it will cause my site performance to be slower, since on every-page the PHP will scan all ID etc..?

Comment: If I purchased a theme that has regular updates, where is the best place to copy template files to so that my changes aren't overwritten by updates? Thanks for your answer above.

Comment: With above answer, your changes wouldn't be overwritten

Comment: @Christia I meant putting your tpl files in your own subtheme of the bought one. This is always a good practice to create a subtheme of any one your installed.  So that you can update the main theme anytime.

Answer (score 1):

When using the solution form @Kojo, if you don't want to use your own module, create a function in `template.php`:

```php
function THEMENAME_form_FORMID_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    //...
}
```

For example

```php
function bartik_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    //...
}
```

This code will change all comment forms, you can be more specific and provide an id of the form of some type. To get the *FORMID*, open the rendered page and find the following field in html:

```
<input type="hidden" value="HERE-WILL-BE-THE-FORMID" name="form_id">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by loading the comment form.

$comment = comment_load($cid); // $cid is comment id
$form = drupal_get_form('comment_form', $comment); 
print drupal_render($form);

url: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_load/7.x